# Нестандартная сортировка в XML / XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

Есть xml. Формирую из него Html страничку.

```
<price>
    <period cost="1000.0000" type="3" typename="year" length="1">1 год</period>
    <period cost="99.0000" type="1" typename="month" length="1">1 месяц</period>
    <period cost="250.0000" type="1" typename="month" length="3">3 месяца</period>
    <period cost="500.0000" type="1" typename="month" length="6">6 месяцев</period>
    <period cost="14990.0000" type="0" typename="day" length="" >Бессрочная лицензия</period>
</price>
```

Как организовать сортировку для цикла чтоб сначала шел нод **1 месяц, 2 месяца ... 1 год.., Бессрочная лицензия** ?

```
<xsl:for-each select="price/period">
    <xsl:sort select="???"/>
    <!--мои действия с нодом -->
</xsl:for-each>
```

нужно как-то организовать функцию сортировки с условием что-то типа

**мнемокод**

```
if type = 1 then return length * 30
if type = 3 then return length * 365
if type = 0 then return 1000000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По-моему, проще всего будет сделать сортировку по цене:

```
<xsl:for-each select="price/period">
    <xsl:sort select="@cost" data-type="number"/>
    <!-- -->
</xsl:for-each>
```

Также можно сортировать по длине атрибута `typename` в обратном порядке. Сортировки можно применять последовательно, вторая будет сортировать по атрибуту `length`; таким образом, группа месяцев тоже отсортируется:

```
<xsl:for-each select="price/period">
    <xsl:sort select="string-length(@typename)" order="descending"/>
    <xsl:sort select="@length" data-type="number"/>
    <!-- -->
</xsl:for-each>
```

Если по какой-то причине можно использовать только `type` и `length`, то делаем так:

```
<xsl:for-each select="price/period[@type!='0']">
    <xsl:sort select="@type" data-type="number"/>
    <xsl:sort select="@length" data-type="number"/>
    <!-- -->
</xsl:for-each>

<xsl:for-each select="price/period[@type='0']">
    <!-- -->
</xsl:for-each>
```

Атрибут `type` со значением `0` обрабатываем отдельно, вручную размещая его после остальных. А все другие сортируем по типу и длине.

Comment: по цене сделать сортировку хорошая идея. спасибо! не догадался.